# Forecasting More than One Column

Tags: r, forecasting

How do I run this for each of the 50 columns I have instead of one at a time?

```
#Chosen vector creation
IMBFM <- as.numeric(data$IMBFM)

#Hidden layers creation
alpha <- 1.5^(-10)
hn <- length(IMBFM)/(alpha*(length(IMBFM)+30))

#Fitting nnetar
lambda <- BoxCox.lambda(IMBFM)
dnn_pred <- nnetar(IMBFM, size= hn, lambda = lambda)

#Fitting nnetar
dnn_forecast <- forecast(dnn_pred, h= 30, PI = TRUE)
dnn_forecast
plot(dnn_forecast)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample data using `dput(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes your column, and returns a list of the forecast and the plot

```
f <- function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  alpha <- 1.5^(-10)
  hn <- length(x)/(alpha*(length(x)+30))
  lambda <- BoxCox.lambda(x)
  dnn_pred <- nnetar(x, size= hn, lambda = lambda)
  dnn_forecast <- forecast(dnn_pred, h= 30, PI = TRUE)
  return(
    list("forecast" = dnn_forecast, "plot" = plot(dnn_forecast))
  )
}
```

Create a vector of your columns of interest / many ways to do this; this is the manual way, but your might be able to use a regex on `colnames(data)` to select the ones of interest, depending on the names

```
mycols = c("IBMF", "col2", "col3", ... "col50")
```

Use `lapply` to apply the function to each element of `mycols`

```
result = lapply(mycols, function(col) data[[col]])
```